# Is function application applied from right to left?

Tags: haskell

Why does this work:

```
isValid :: String -> Bool
isValid =  (>= 10) . length
```

whereas this doesn't?

```
isValid :: String -> Bool
isValid =  length . (>= 10)
```

===>

```
    • Couldn't match type ‘Int’ with ‘Bool’
      Expected type: String -> Bool
        Actual type: String -> Int
```

Aren't they the same? Does function application work from right to left and not vise versa?

Comment: The pronunciation of `(.)` that I like is "after." Try saying your two definitions out loud.

Comment: @HTNW That seems like it would just propagate the misconception that precedence and evaluation order are the same thing. Consider `const 123 . undefined`.

Comment: "Throw away the result and return `123` after applying `undefined`"? Makes sense to me.

Comment: @HTNW But you never apply `undefined`. If you did, then the program would crash before it could throw away the result.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica That's not how `undefined` works. Semantically, `undefined x` just evaluates to `undefined`. *Technically*, it only blows up once that `undefined` bubbles up to an `IO` action, and "the program" itself becomes undefined. Note that Haskell isn't built under the assumption of lazy evaluation, it's built under the assumption that *evaluation order doesn't matter.* If you think of evaluation correctly, you *always* get the right answer no matter how you do it, as long as you don't get stuck in an infinite loop unnecessarily.

Comment: @HTNW Okay, how about `trace "foo" id . trace "bar" id`? `foo` will print before `bar`.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica That's easy: you cannot talk about `trace` from this level of abstraction. This level of abstraction only concerns itself with the results of expressions, where it correctly says that you get `id`. Things like "efficiency" and "the order of `trace` messages" are implementation details from up here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211047/discussion-between-htnw-and-joseph-sible-reinstate-monica).

Comment: The signatures go from left to right, the application goes from right to left. Yes, could be confusing.

Comment: If you want left to right composition there's `>>>` (works for arrows)

Comment: Just looking at the type of `(.)` should be enough to convince you that `(.)` is not commutative. `(b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c` is not symmetric with respect to `a`, `b`, and `c`.

Comment: granted, only a fragment of the error message was included in the post, but still the dv's seem excessive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`isValid =  (>= 10) . length` is equivalent to `isValid x = (length x) >= 10`, but `isValid =  length . (>= 10)` is equivalent to `isValid x = length (x >= 10)`, which is clearly nonsense. When **composing** (not applying) functions with `.`, the rightmost one is applied to the input, and ones on the left receive as inputs the outputs from the ones on the right.

Answer (score 5):

Function *composition* (not application) is what you are using.  `h = f . g` is `h x = f (g x)`.  Thus if you write `g . f` that would be `h x = g (f x)` which certainly isn't the same thing.